# How to send Push Notification Firebase

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

I am new to `Firebase` and the main reason I adapted to it from my old MySql DB is the ability to send push notification and dynamic links. I have been trying for the past two days to send notification to a group of people who have subscribed to a topic from my `node.js` script. The script always returns `InternalServerError`. I am able to send notification from the `Firebase` console but that is not good enough for my app as I need to implement dynamic notification (i.e. triggered by one users action).

So far I did not understand what was in the official docs and tried following a tutorial I found and I am currently here

```
app.get('/push',function(req,res){
  /*var title = req.params.title;
  var body = req.params.body;*/
//  var confName = req.params.name;
  var message = { //this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera)
      to: '/topics/ilisten',
    //  collapse_key: 'your_collapse_key',

      notification: {
          title: 'This is Title',
          body: 'This is body'
      },

      data: {  //you can send only notification or only data(or include both)
          my_key: 'Conf Name here'
      }
  };
  fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!"+err);
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
    }
});
})
```

My first question is what should I do in the `to` field so that all the users in my app reciece the notification.

I would also like to take a look at correct and complete implementation of this concept with android code. If anyone has such code please share it here as it would help the future `Firebase` users who cannot understand the official docs like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is one approach using `node-gcm` (https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm)

```
  var gcm = require('node-gcm');

  var sender = new gcm.Sender(<sender_key>);

  var message = new gcm.Message();
  message.addNotification('title', title);
  message.addNotification('body', body);

  sender.send(message, { topic: "/topics/" + topic }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: @john-oreilly  I think it would be useful for future visitors if you could explain how to send a notification to all the users.

Comment: @NirmalRaj  this will send message to all users that have subscribed to the given `topic`

Comment: @john-oreilly Is there any way to send messages to all the users who have installed my app. For. eg the one we can do from the firebase console